# Draw a border around a SKLabelNode

Tags: ios, border, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I'm making an app in which I'm using [SKLabelNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html). 
I would like to put a border around it.

This is my code sofar:

```
SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNames:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
scoreLabel.text = @"@";
scoreLabel.alpha = 1;
scoreLabel.fontSize = 30;
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(149,525);
[self addChild:scoreLabel];
```

Also, would anyone know how to use a custom font for this?

Say I make my own font, and then want to put a border around it, how would I do this?

Comment: border as in highlight? You could display the same label with the exact same parameters and same position, but fontSize slightly larger. Add that label first so it is displayed under the actual label.

Comment: You could also use a regular and bold font of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I would say [BMGlyph](http://www.bmglyph.com) is the way to go. I use it all the time.